# So long, and thanks for all the fish?

Tags: story, treasure-hunt, three-dimensional

> ```
> Date: 5/25/6913
>
> Recap for new recruits:
>
> As you know, the dolphins left Earth for reasons unknown to us.  Their last
> message to us included the phrase "So long, and thanks for all the fish"
> and something about a "treasure" floating around, but we are unclear on what.
> The eggheads back on Earth had decoded their message to the attached image.
> I hope you all can figure out that it's some kind of solar system.  As we
> traveled, Earth has made a few more observations of this system.  First, the
> planets seen to move counter-clockwise around the star.  Second, with
> respect to the image, planets seem to move 1 space per day.  Third, the
> moons travel clockwise around the planets, making a full revolution once
> every 4 days.  Fourth, the system is pretty small, so our current
> technology can travel to any point over the course of 1 day.
>
> Current status:
>
> We have finally arrived at the system.  Our sensors are still out from
> yesterday, but we managed to land on a planet.  Upon landing, we exited
> the ship and saw a book set out at the base of the ramp, as if someone
> knew exactly where we would land.  Unfortunately, a bowl of petunias
> was crushed by our ramp lowering, but the book was in great condition.
> Inside the book was the following note.
>
> "Welcome humans!  You've finally made it.  Sorry for the poor
> connection, we are heading through a space tunnel at the moment.
> Anyway, the 4 images in this book were created by our astronomers
> over drinks at some restaurant.  The first one should be pretty
> similar to where you are now, with the rest hopefully becoming
> clear as you travel to them.  Anyway, you'll need to work quickly
> or the pictures will get all out of whack and some kind of time
> traveling destroy-the-universe stuff will happen, which is
> undesirable for all involved parties.  Before you get your hopes up
> too much, the treasure is going to be a random person floating in
> the expanse of space.  Please be of some use and pick them up in a
> timely manner.  Oh, almost forgot, when you get to the last location,
> the guy will be 1GS, which means [static]"
> ```

Not sure exactly how it happened, but the note turned into static.  There's no time to be confused though, there's a potential time-traveling <strike>bug</strike> feature to deal with!  Oh, and some guy floating in the vast nothingness of space that we should probably save, even if he hasn't ever done anything for us.

[image: Initial image]

[image: 4 images]

Comment: Potential grammatical errors are unintended.

Comment: is the $\wedge$GN in the top right corner of the map the direction towards Galactic North?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of the writing of the note, the planets and moons are not in the position originally shown because:

> The date of the image is `3/27/4824`, and the letter (today, for all intents and purposes) is `5/25/6913`. Because today need not be included, it's 960281 days later (thanks, http://www.calculator.net/).
>
>  Counting the orbital periods from the inside out, they are (in days):
>  `8, 12, 15, 22, 30, 36`
>
>  Taking the total days mod the orbital period yields the current position, again from the inside out:
>  `1, 5, 11, 3, 11, 17`
>
>  To add, the orbital period of all the moons is 4 days. `960281 % 4 = 1`, so all the moons will be opposite their current orientation.

So the today's orientation of the planets looks like (T+0):

> [image: system, fixed]

And we know that it will take 1 full day to travel to the other locations, of which there are 3. This means we will need 3 single day iterations, which should look like this:

T+1

> [image: T+1]

T+2

> [image: T+2]

T+3

> [image: T+3]

On the subject of the lower 4 images:

> I'm still not sure about the journey, but it looks to me like the lower right image with the eclipse matches with T+3, and the red planet is the one indicated.

So the treasure is ...

> As pointed out by @elias the key is shows Galactic North. It should follow then that the note points to Galactic South. Since the journey should end at the red planet, our floating man (Arthur Dent or Ford Prefect, perhaps? ha) will be 1 sector south of the red planet, in empty space.

Comment: great work, but do not forget that planets move counter-clockwise around their sun.

Comment: Wow. I read that, but totally forgot when I started counting. That's why none of the other images made sense ...

Comment: @Matt Also noteworthy, since the original image is the layout on that day, you do not need to add 1 to the final day total.  Example: if "today" was `3/28/4824` the number of days would be 1, not 2.  Just wouldn't want you to create the image all over again and it end up off by a single day.

Comment: Again, I was struggling to make sense of things. Thanks for the nudge.

Comment: @DavidStarkey I'm done fixing this image, right? :P

Comment: I've edited the question to hopefully explain better.  You will be traveling to each location and using another image to continue towards the "treasure".  That's part of where the time-traveling bit comes in.  Aside from that, your image looks good.

Comment: @Matt Getting closer, but remember that it takes a day for you to travel to each of the locations.

Comment: One day, I'll be good at following instructions. Hopefully soon ...

Comment: @DavidStarkey I have day 0 - day 3 system layouts ... now trying to fit the 4 images

Comment: @Matt You technically have the answer, but I would still like to see all the images mapped up to the journey.  Perhaps I should have included something in the story that required you to go to each location.

Comment: I had a really hard time trying to work those out visually. Thanks for the checkmark, though. I will try to revisit this when I have the time ...